# Ho do I create a new column and values to it

Tags: python, pandas

I have two csv files with data. They both have a common column (county). The first file just has the counties while the second file has counties together with their population. I have a script which I thought would be able to create a new column of population in the first file. Note that the order of the counties in both files is totally different.

File one:

| Id | County |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Nairobi |
| 2 | Mombasa |
| 3 | Kisumu |
| 4 | Nakuru |

File two:

| Id | County | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kisumu | 1,250,200 |
| 2 | Nairobi | 4,560,700 |
| 3 | Nakuru | 2,673,800 |
| 4 | Mombasa | 3,167,900 |

I wanted to create a new column in the first table as Population and parse through the second table and pick population of each county, like in the table below.

| Id | County | Population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nairobi | 4,560,700 |
| 2 | Mombasa | 3,167,900 |
| 3 | Kisumu | 1,250,200 |
| 4 | Nakuru | 2,673,800 |

Below is my code, I got a bit confused on how to execute that. Please help.

````
data = pd.read_csv('counties.csv');
county_names = data['COUNTY']

ref_data = pd.read_csv('kenya-population-by-sex-and-county.csv', skiprows=8, header=None)
ref_data.columns = ['County', 'Male', 'Female', 'Intersex', 'Total']

list_count = []
for item in county_names.tolist():
    compare = ref_data['County'].tolist()
    pop = ref_data['Total']
    if item in compare:
        list_count.append(item)
        pop
    else:
        print(item + " is not in list")```
````

Comment: Let me take a look at it

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create a pandas dataframe containing County and Population and merge it with the first dataframe where only County was there. Also there are many joining options available to fulfill your different needs.